# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'modifier')

Tags: tailwind-css

Project: vue3+vite+ts, created by npm init vue@latest
Software: phpstorm
Problems and errors:
The style has taken effect, but the ide does not have any intellisense and reports an error
Error notification:Tailwind CSS: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'modifier')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using phpstorm, it has nothing to do with vscode.
But the problem is found, the tailwindcss plugin built in phpstorm has not been updated, it is currently incompatible with taiwindcss 3.2

Answer (score 0):

[Same issue here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense/issues/641)

Just update your extension to >=`0.9.0`

And you may need to update your vscode too, because higher version of the extension won't work with old versions of vscode

Comment: I'm using phpstorm, it has nothing to do with vscode.
But the problem is found, the tailwindcss plugin built in phpstorm has not been updated, it is currently incompatible with taiwindcss 3.2